# How to correctly express "Under all the assumptions but this one"?

Tags: sentence-construction

I would like to express "under all the assumptions, except a certain one (call this certain one A), of the theorem, we construct...". If it can be shortened, then the first thought that came to me was "under all but the A assumptions of the theorem, we construct...". However, this seems not grammatical and confusing.

Is my evaluation true? If not, what would be a better option out there? Thanks.

Comment: Try replacing *but* with *except*: **The theorem is true under all of the assumptions except assumption A.**

Comment: @MichaelRybkin, Hi. Thanks. The order of "under ..." would be important for my case. I updated my question by providing a more detailed picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problems in your original sentence is that your use of commas creates parenthetical information. You don't want to do that because you've put *except* inside that parenthetical information. That makes it nonessential when it actually *is* essential to what you want to say.

Your revised sentence is talks about *A assumptions* (plural), yet you've previously indicated that there is only a single exception. (Perhaps the *s* is a typo.)

I suggest this:

> Under all but one assumption of the theorem (call the exception A), we construct . . .

What's in parentheses can be removed without causing harm to the sentence. It's up to you if you want to mention that you're going to call the exception *A* or not.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. There are more than one assumptions out there; in this case, is it still okay to use the construction by dropping the redundant "s"? I used "s" because there are more than one assumptions. Please, thanks.

Comment: @GaryMoore But there is only one assumption that will not be used, correct? If so, the singular is correct, syntactically. In *all but* ***one assumption***, there can be any number of assumptions (plural) that *are* used—so long as there's a single one that is *not*. If there were two assumptions not used (among many more), then you would say *under all but* ***two assumptions***.

Comment: I see! Thanks. That answers my question completely.